# Selenium iFrame inputText

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to build a test automation where the html is in an iFrame, I was able to find online the lines of code to activate the iFrame, click on a link, and press a button and they are working fine -see following lines:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("06634000000BVL6");
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Loan Details R1")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Edit')]")).Click();
```

I needed to input a text within a textBox in that iFrame, but I couldn't handle the ID or the Class, below is the HTML for the input:

input Element in the Webpage is here

```html
<input ng-if="$ctrl.fieldType.isText($ctrl.field.fieldType)" ng-model="$ctrl.field.value" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" ng-required="$ctrl.field.isRequired" type="text" ng-class="{
    'input-sm': true,
    'form-control': true,
    'nc-pristine': $ctrl.getPristine(),
    'nc-not-pristine': $ctrl.getNotPristine()
   }" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched">
```

**FULL HTML of the Screen Section**

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-single">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-wrapper">
 <div class="row view-container">
       <message class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="slds">       <!-- ngRepeat: message in vm.processMessages(vm.messages) -->      </div></message>
       <nc-screen-section-form-builder context-id="a3818000000IKS5AAO" default-editable="true" guid="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO6749053A65524CADB34D77EAD85598EF" is-editable="true" section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <form name="$ctrl.generatedForm" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
      <!-- ngRepeat: field in $ctrl.getFields() as fields --><!-- ngIf: $index % 2 == 0 --><div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="field in $ctrl.getFields() as fields" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
       <!-- ngRepeat: i in [$index, $index + 1] --><!-- ngIf: fields[i] --><nc-form-group-template ng-repeat="i in [$index, $index + 1]" ng-if="fields[i]" section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" guid="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO6749053A65524CADB34D77EAD85598EF" field="fields[i]" context-id="a3818000000IKS5AAO" ,="" enable-field-access="$ctrl.enableFieldAccess" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
   <nc-field-label-template section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" field="$ctrl.field" inline-help-text="If [New Loan + Non-Resi RE Sec + LoanAmt<=$1MM] or [Purch/Refi/Improv of 1-4 family + 1-4 family secured term/perm loan], select &quot;None of the above&quot; as CRA purpose is not needed." label="CRA CDL Justification" is-required="$ctrl.field.isRequired" enable-field-access="$ctrl.enableFieldAccess" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="row content-label">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <span ng-show="$ctrl.inlineHelpText" popover="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-content="If [New Loan + Non-Resi RE Sec + LoanAmt<=$1MM] or [Purch/Refi/Improv of 1-4 family + 1-4 family secured term/perm loan], select &quot;None of the above&quot; as CRA purpose is not needed." class="fa fa-info-circle slds-show--inline" data-original-title="" title="">
    </span>
    <label ng-bind="$ctrl.label" class="form-control-static input-sm slds-show--inline ng-binding is-required" ng-class="{'is-required': $ctrl.isRequired, 'pull-left': $ctrl.enableFieldAccess}">CRA CDL Justification</label>
    <span class="slds-p-left--medium">
     <!-- ngIf: !$ctrl.field.isVisible && $ctrl.enableFieldAccess -->
     <span class="slds-assistive-text">This field will be hidden from the user.</span>
    </span>
    <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.enableFieldAccess -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </nc-field-label-template>
   <!-- ngIf: !$ctrl.isReadOnly() --><nc-editable-field-template ng-if="!$ctrl.isReadOnly()" section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" guid="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO6749053A65524CADB34D77EAD85598EF" field="$ctrl.field" context-id="a3818000000IKS5AAO" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 content-body">
    <nc-editable-field section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" guid="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO6749053A65524CADB34D77EAD85598EF" field="$ctrl.field" context-id="a3818000000IKS5AAO" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isText($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isCheckBox($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isComboBox($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isCurrency($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isDate($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isDateTime($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isDouble($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isEmail($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isEncryptedString($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isId($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isInteger($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isPicklist($ctrl.field.fieldType) --><nc-pick-list ng-if="$ctrl.fieldType.isPicklist($ctrl.field.fieldType)" section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" guid="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO6749053A65524CADB34D77EAD85598EF" field="$ctrl.field" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <div>
   <select ng-model="$ctrl.field.value" ng-required="$ctrl.field.isRequired" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in $ctrl.field.options | filter: {available:true}" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" ng-class="{
     'input-sm': true,
     'checkbox-inline': true,
     'form-control': true,
     'nc-pristine': $ctrl.getPristine(),
     'nc-not-pristine': $ctrl.getNotPristine()
    }" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required input-sm checkbox-inline form-control nc-pristine" required="required"><option value="" class="ng-binding" selected="selected">--None--</option><option label="Affordable housing for Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) individuals. Please provide the % of units below 80% of AMI." value="string:Affordable housing for Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) individuals. Please provide the % of units below 80% of AMI.">Affordable housing for Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) individuals. Please provide the % of units below 80% of AMI.</option><option label="Community services to Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) individuals. Please Describe." value="string:Community services to Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) individuals. Please Describe.">Community services to Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) individuals. Please Describe.</option><option label="Economic development by financing for small businesses and small farms with GAR of $1 million or less. Please Describe." value="string:Economic development by financing for small businesses and small farms with GAR of $1 million or less. Please Describe.">Economic development by financing for small businesses and small farms with GAR of $1 million or less. Please Describe.</option><option label="Revitalization or stabilization of a Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) geography. Please Describe." value="string:Revitalization or stabilization of a Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) geography. Please Describe.">Revitalization or stabilization of a Low- to Moderate-Income (LMI) geography. Please Describe.</option><option label="Non-CRA CDL" value="string:Non-CRA CDL">Non-CRA CDL</option></select>
  </div>
 </nc-pick-list><!-- end ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isPicklist($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isMultiPicklist($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isPercent($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isPhone($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isReference($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isTextarea($ctrl.field.fieldType, $ctrl.field.isHtmlFormatted) -->


  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isRichText($ctrl.field.fieldType, $ctrl.field.isHtmlFormatted) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isUrl($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->
 </nc-editable-field>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nc-editable-field-template><!-- end ngIf: !$ctrl.isReadOnly() -->
   <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.isReadOnly() -->
  </div>
 </nc-form-group-template><!-- end ngIf: fields[i] --><!-- end ngRepeat: i in [$index, $index + 1] --><!-- ngIf: fields[i] --><nc-form-group-template ng-repeat="i in [$index, $index + 1]" ng-if="fields[i]" section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" guid="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO6749053A65524CADB34D77EAD85598EF" field="fields[i]" context-id="a3818000000IKS5AAO" ,="" enable-field-access="$ctrl.enableFieldAccess" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
   <nc-field-label-template section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" field="$ctrl.field" inline-help-text="" label="CRA CDL Justification Comments" is-required="$ctrl.field.isRequired" enable-field-access="$ctrl.enableFieldAccess" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="row content-label">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <span ng-show="$ctrl.inlineHelpText" popover="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-content="" class="fa fa-info-circle slds-show--inline ng-hide" data-original-title="" title="">
    </span>
    <label ng-bind="$ctrl.label" class="form-control-static input-sm slds-show--inline ng-binding" ng-class="{'is-required': $ctrl.isRequired, 'pull-left': $ctrl.enableFieldAccess}">CRA CDL Justification Comments</label>
    <span class="slds-p-left--medium">
     <!-- ngIf: !$ctrl.field.isVisible && $ctrl.enableFieldAccess -->
     <span class="slds-assistive-text">This field will be hidden from the user.</span>
    </span>
    <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.enableFieldAccess -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </nc-field-label-template>
   <!-- ngIf: !$ctrl.isReadOnly() --><nc-editable-field-template ng-if="!$ctrl.isReadOnly()" section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" guid="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO6749053A65524CADB34D77EAD85598EF" field="$ctrl.field" context-id="a3818000000IKS5AAO" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 content-body">
    <nc-editable-field section-id="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO" guid="a1g18000000ZYQkAAO6749053A65524CADB34D77EAD85598EF" field="$ctrl.field" context-id="a3818000000IKS5AAO" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isText($ctrl.field.fieldType) --><input ng-if="$ctrl.fieldType.isText($ctrl.field.fieldType)" ng-model="$ctrl.field.value" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" ng-required="$ctrl.field.isRequired" type="text" ng-class="{
    'input-sm': true,
    'form-control': true,
    'nc-pristine': $ctrl.getPristine(),
    'nc-not-pristine': $ctrl.getNotPristine()
   }" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched"><!-- end ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isText($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isCheckBox($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isComboBox($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isCurrency($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isDate($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isDateTime($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isDouble($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isEmail($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isEncryptedString($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isId($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isInteger($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isPicklist($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isMultiPicklist($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isPercent($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isPhone($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isReference($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isTextarea($ctrl.field.fieldType, $ctrl.field.isHtmlFormatted) -->


  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isRichText($ctrl.field.fieldType, $ctrl.field.isHtmlFormatted) -->

  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isUrl($ctrl.field.fieldType) -->
 </nc-editable-field>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nc-editable-field-template><!-- end ngIf: !$ctrl.isReadOnly() -->
   <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.isReadOnly() -->
  </div>
 </nc-form-group-template><!-- end ngIf: fields[i] --><!-- end ngRepeat: i in [$index, $index + 1] -->
      </div><!-- end ngIf: $index % 2 == 0 --><!-- end ngRepeat: field in $ctrl.getFields() as fields --><!-- ngIf: $index % 2 == 0 --><!-- end ngRepeat: field in $ctrl.getFields() as fields -->
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.scriptBlock" class="ng-binding"></div>
 </nc-screen-section-form-builder>
 </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you please share error trace ?

Comment: Can you share ur code which u have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned any stacktrace and your attempted code. even though based on your provided input element, use below code

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched']")).SendKeys("sometest");
```

This should work for sure. Make sure you have switch into correct Frame

Comment: @Sam, if this answer is helpful for you then don't forget to accept and upvote